# How can I set application layout properties in a theme?

Tags: xpages

I understand how to set properties like style and styleClass using a theme but how do I set  a property such as productLogo in my theme?

I tried

```
<control>
    <name>ApplicationLayout</name>
    <property>
        <name>configuration.oneuiApplication.productLogo</name>
        <value>"/LogoSmall.JPG"</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

and

```
<control>
    <name>ApplicationLayout</name>
    <property>
        <name>configuration.productLogo</name>
        <value>"/LogoSmall.JPG"</value>
    </property>
</control>





<control>
    <name>ApplicationLayout</name>
    <property>
        <name>productLogo</name>
        <value>"/LogoSmall.JPG"</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

but none seemed to work.

Can this be done?  If so how?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to determine the themeID of the component. Tim Tripcony has wrote a blog about how to do this, see http://xmage.gbs.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-8RXAQ6
When you know the theme id you can use in your own theme

Comment: I know the theme ID.  It is ApplicationLayout.  What I need to know is how to set the properties of the component.  My post above shows the theme ID of the application component.

Comment: I think the syntax of the value should be <value>/LogoSmall.JPG</value>

Comment: Applying properties of a layout via a theme would only be of incremental value, since most applications only contain one. The power of themes is most effectively realized by uniformly applying properties to numerous instances of a given type of control across an entire application.

Comment: Being uniform is  what I am trying to do. Each time you add an application control to a page or custom control you have properties to set.  Multiple that over a few hundred applications which can have the theme updated via a template (optional) and you are talking about lots of properties.  Yes this could also be down through a custom control but doing it through a theme seems more flexible since you can develop your own pages with application controls without having to worry about setting all of the properties.